# RAILS :RESTclient request body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rest, rest-client

I am trying to use the **rest-client** library of rails.
Can anyone help me understand this code.

```
RestClient::Resource.new(@service_url).put :account => {:db_url => @config_vars['DATABASE_URL']}
```

I know it sends a put REST request, but how is the  `:account => {:db_url => @config_vars['DATABASE_URL']}`part sent. I mean, what will the body of the request be like?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request body of the PUT request will be JSON:

```
"account": {
  "db_url": <whatever @config_vars['DATABASE_URL'] is>
}
```

Comment: it should be {  "account": {
  "db_url": <whatever @config_vars['DATABASE_URL'] is>
} } though, no?